# Absorption Law with Negation

Tags: propositional-calculus

Would absorption law work for statements with neagations in them like $( \neg q \land \neg r) \lor r$?

Comment: Is the absorption law the distribution law?

Comment: but isn't distributive law the case where the 3 variables are all different?

Comment: According to wikipedia there is an absorption law that states that if $P \rightarrow Q$ then $P \rightarrow P \wedge Q.$

Comment: So if I simplified this would I get $(r \lor \neg q) \land (r \lor \neg r)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:
$$
( \neg Q \land \neg R) \lor R  = (\neg Q \lor R) \land (\neg R \lor R)
$$

Note that $\neg R \lor R$ is always true, so the above becomes: $$\neg Q \lor R.$$